# How to get the Buttons on an DialogFragment as Flat Style?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-dialogfragment

maybe im just blind. In an Dialog Fragment i inflate some custom layout.
No styles are used on that Button. I use Holo.Light as a Theme. But the Button is not
in that flat style.

How can i archive this ?

Cheers,
Kitesurfer

Comment: can you show some screen shots of what you're talking about? what you want it to look like and what it looks like now would help, also if you post your XML we can show you what you might have done wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the correct style. I'm using the following (should work on HoneyComb+):

```
<LinearLayout
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/positive"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_done"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negative"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is there some way that i can do this in a Theme ?

Comment: So far looks ok, i miss those smaller lines around the buttons. Actually i get the flat style but you cannot see the width of the button

Comment: I'm fairly certain you set it in a theme for your app. As for the width, you can kind of control it with the `LinearLayout`. The buttons are each 50% of the width of the container. You can add padding, a background or whatever you want to make them stand out a bit more.